# For PC gaming on external storage, should I use Flash or HDD (hard disk drive)?

Tags: pc, hardware, hard-drive

I will be playing PC games on external memory via a **USB 3.0** connection. Ignoring price and memory capacity differences, which of these options is better for *gameplay* purposes?:

- a Flash USB (generally better at transferring many small files), or
- an External Hard Disk Drive (HDD) (generally better at transferring large files)

I've been told that the main downside to gaming externally is slower load times. In general, is loading, mainly heaps of small files or a couple of large files?

If it matters, the type of game I will be playing is Fallout 4, a large open world game.

I'm using a MacBook Pro, Retina, Mid 2012. Running Windows 8.1 via Boot Camp. I have SSD internal storage, but only about 35GB left on the partition for Windows.

Which memory type should I use if I'm gaming externally? Flash or external HDD?

Comment: Have you ever considered an SSD instead?

Comment: To qualify as USB 3.0 a device only needs to run at a speed higher than USB 2.0 allows, which is not fast at all. Specific devices for comparison will play a role in the answer, as differences between them, even in the same class, can be great. It would also seem that neither will match internal HDD connected with SATA, but who knows, it might prove to be enough.

Comment: I have considered an SSD. They have been ruled out due to price.

Comment: You really don't even need that much space anyways. Hell, many people tend to simply invest in a smaller size and install Windows only on that and the rest on an HDD. That makes things *a lot* speedier.

Comment: Your best bet is a external HDD. You won't gain much from a external SSD if you can't use a esata connection.

Comment: Could you clarify your use case? Do you need an external drive because upgrading or replacing an internal is not an option? If you go external you'd need to pay carefuly attention to the USB controller of whatever device/enclosure you're using as they might very well throttle to SATA 3 speeds or lower.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, using Windows via Boot Camp. I don't want my partition to be too big since I mainly use the Mac part of my computer. I am considering re-partitioning my hard drive so that I can play it internally, but I haven't decided yet. If I do so, I would still only have room for one game.

Comment: I suppose this is on-topic here but you'd be more likely to get in-depth and sourced answers on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Unless using USB3, and an enclosure that takes advantage of that. http://www.itworld.com/article/2693284/usb-3-0-vs-esata-is-faster-better.html (brief example, though it is rather old)

Comment: The Wii-U basically requires a powered external hard drive.  So at least one major gaming company has implicitly supported powered external HDDs.

Comment: I would suggest moving your mac stuff to the external device and keeping your game stuff on the internal drive if adding an extra internal drive or upgrading the internal drive isn't an option.

Comment: What model Macintosh is this?

Comment: MacBook Pro, Retina, Mid 2012

Comment: You ruled out SSD by price, but you say to ignore price. Top end Flash drives, which can be extremely fast and reliable these days (performance and reliability vary considerably between makes and models, though, reading a million reviews is practically a requirement), can easily be more expensive than bottom end SSD.

Comment: @Mel Good. The on-chip Intel HD Graphics 4000 would never run Fallout 4, I have the same on my Macbook, but the dedicated GeForce GT 650M will do ok. That said, I think your graphics card will be the biggest bottleneck. Have you tried running a modern triple-A FPS like Battlefield 4 or Arma 3?

Comment: I doubt you can really make this work well. There's likely to be significant lag. I tried to run Windows on VMWare on my external drive and it was simply impossible. I don't think running games is going to be better than running VM. Your best bet is still to play the game on your internal hard drive/gaming console, though maybe you can give a try with SSD. Also I believe most modern games have OS X versions already.

Comment: Could the user who voted to close this as off topic please give their arguments why they think this is off-topic? While a skim read might send up a flare to direct this to SuperUser, the question is about use for the purpose of gaming. This is a very useful question to have on here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe neither are good options.

Running Fallout 4 will most likely keep the drive active for the entire duration of your playtime.  Neither external flash nor HDD have sufficient heat dissipation to handle that.  You will most likely destroy your drive very quickly.

Unfortunately you probably won't know this is happening because the external drive are typically housed in a box.  You will have to take the device apart to notice this.

If you are still considering this, look for a high quality, metal external drive, with an active heat sink (has a fan) and also heat sink fins on the box.  However, these are significantly more expensive.

As an alternative, the 1.8"/2.5" format is usually safer.  The HDD itself are designed for laptops, and usually generates less heat because the "boxed in" environment are exactly how they operate in a laptop.  However, do look for a metal one that feels cool to the touch (heat dissipation), and avoid plastic ones.

Note: your HDD itself will most like be fine, but the enclosure is usually a cheap plastic box with no holes.  Cheap plastic electronic + heat is usually a combination to stay away from :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26806/discussion-on-answer-by-nelson-for-pc-gaming-on-external-storage-should-i-use-f).

Comment: If it wasn't clear from my last comment, further discussion should be done **[in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26806/discussion-on-answer-by-nelson-for-pc-gaming-on-external-storage-should-i-use-f)**

Comment: @StrixVaria: Righto, clear. Is there any chance the discussion that happened in the last 20 hours could be moved to the chat? [I am aware that comments do not have history, etc, so it's unlikely that they're still stored/accessible]

Comment: @Jeeva Unfortunately, no; comments can only be chat-migrated once per post.

Comment: @StrixVaria Unfortunate, but it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

These are your options in order from best to worst:

## Solid State Drive (SSD)

A solid state drive will provide much faster access than a mechanical hard drive. Amazon shows that in August 2015 you can get 250GB external SSD for around $150. According to [Game Debate](http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=5013&game=Fallout%204) Fallout 4 requires 28GB of hard drive space so you could target an even smaller drive to reduce costs. You may also choose to assemble your own drive by purchasing an internal SSD and a 2.5 inch USB 3 Enclosure to contain the drive. The enclosure should be able to be found for around $10.

You should be able to assemble a 120GB drive for under $70 and a 60GB drive for around $50 from either Amazon or your local computer parts store. My examples above are assuming you are in the USA, but as another example here in Australia I could assemble a 120GB SSD in a USB 3 enclosure for under $90 AUD.

## Powered 3.5 Inch Mechanical Drive

A powered external drive will be larger than a portable drive (and not very useful if you are on the go) but it will provide ample space (multiple terabytes) and should perform similar to a mechanical hard drive that you would have found inside a desktop PC a few years ago. Note that these days most "gaming" PCs will be built with Solid State Drives internally.

## "Pocket" 2.5 Inch Mechanical Drive

A pocket drive is still usable, and can be found quite readily and cheaply. Be prepared for long loading times and transitions, and also long install times when using Steam as it will have to pause during downloading to wait for all the files to be unpacked to the disk. I had significant success using one of these drives a few years ago to play games under Boot Camp on a MacBook Pro, allowing me to install lots of games but keep a small (20GB) Boot Camp partition.

## Flash Drives / Memory Cards

Even though flash drives have no moving parts like an SSD, there is still a large performance difference between the two types of drives, especially when reading or writing multiple files at the same time. The performance can be improved by purchasing a high quality (and expensive) memory stick, but at that stage you would be far better off getting a 120 or 240GB SSD.

Comment: In August 2015 you should be able to get a 250GB SSD for under $100.

Comment: +1. Flash drives also have higher failure rates, and can have faster random access than a HDD.

Comment: A quality flash drive can perform 90MB/s read without too much problem, and its easy to carry. It can very easily outperform an average HDD.

Comment: I would put the 2.5 first, they are not more or less prone to failures than their 3.5 cousin.

Comment: -1 for unsourced and doubtful claims. This answer just outlines the commonly known performance differences between SDD and HDD (3.5/2.5") but the performance and impact of the USB3 enclosure and controller are not even mentioned. I'm also not sure how Steam enters into the equation and I doubt that all flash drives are strictly worse than a connected 2.5" enclosure.

Comment: You forgot about other connections like firewire or e-sata.

Comment: > "I had significant success using one of these drives a few years ago to play games under Boot Camp on a MacBook Pro" Really. I didn't have any success trying to run a Windows VM on VMWare with an external drive, so I didn't give this idea any further exploration. So did you still install Bootcamp Windows on the internal hard drive, and only installed the games from Windows on external hard drives?

Comment: Great guide. Talks a lot about price and size, which OP explicitly asks to disregard.

Answer (score 7):

Realistically, the speed of the drive won't affect gameplay much. The main benefit to a HDD would be capacity and price, as an external SSD will not run nearly at the speed the price would imply when connected via USB 3.0. I gamed for quite a while on a USB 2 external HDD, and I never experienced any major issues, save for slightly extended load times.

Comment: Slow HDD performance is awful for games that don't have loading screens. You can encounter a lot of stuttering and freezing while just moving around because it is waiting to load some resource from disk.

Answer (score 4):

If you ruled out an SSD due to price, it's very unlikely that you will get a flash drive with adequate performance. There are fast flash drives, yes. But I never saw a really fast flash drive significantly cheaper than a SSD (per GiB).

Also: Flash Drives don't support the [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28computing%29) command, so they will get slower over time and there is not much one can do (depending on controller: total wipe and write zeroes).
Your use case will delete and write much more than the typical flash drive usage of puting some files there and reading them back, irregularly. So after some time (depending on the amount written during your usage and the free space left on the device) every part of the flash will be used, and there is no way to tell the drive that something is not needed any more. This means on every write the drive has to erase the flash before and copy some data. Performance will be quite bad then.

If you buy a HDD, you should buy a external case with a fan or at least made of aluminium, to spread the heat from the drive.

Answer (score 1):

An SSD or flash drive is not significantly faster for gaming than a traditional hard drive because game assets are packed into big files in the right order for sequential access, negating the SSD's major advantage.

The answer then is "it doesn't matter", whichever is convenient to you.

Comment: Yes, but this is not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This would make a valid answer if you replaced "SSD" with "flash memory", and ensured it all made sense. ie. "either would work fine for gaming, given that ... "

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I beg to differ, it IS an answer.  You get no benefit with an SSD or any type of flash for this type of use so there is no point in paying extra to do that.

Comment: @Timelord64 an SSD uses flash memory. Better quality flash sticks have the same type of wear levelling, the distinction is mainly about marketing and whether it is packaged as a 'stick' or a 'drive' rather than a true difference in capability or performance.  I can understand that you might be confused if you think they are two entirely different things.

Comment: Not at all. But as a type of flash memory, speaking in terms of flash memory in general might put it in context better, and stop the confusion over removing this answer

Comment: Now that you added the "answer part", it feels closer to an actual answer than before. My mileage is quite different as my SSDs make game load times quite lower than my hdd, could argue about what we consider faster for gaming but loading is, imo, part of a gaming experience.

Comment: The other thing, of course, is that as an answer it's demonstrably incorrect (depending on your definition of gaming). SSDs _do_ offer notable QoL benefits for gaming, even when games are optimised for sequential reading (which may be true for games designed to be played from optical media, such as PS2 games). The speed difference for loading assets between, for example, a fast USB3.0 flashdrive and even an internal HDD is notable.

Comment: @Jeeva This has been demonstrated by several well known hardware sites.  It depends on the specific drives in question, a 15k SAS raid would roast a 1 chip USB thumbdrive for instance :).  For most people the actual gain seen in game loading is less than 10% with an SSD and thumbdrives generally slower than HD. For boot and OS drive the gains are much bigger because you are dealing with lots of seeks on small files.

Comment: I totally agree with the idea that the specific drives in question will massively influence the outcome of this... but if we're advising OP, surely the answer is "Yes, by buying the right components, you can gain massively". Flash isn't just about non-existent "seek", it's also rather fast if you get any half-decent product. I'm sure we can chuck links at each other all day, but here's two links showing sequential reads on internal HDDs and flash drives (that are admittedly two years old). Though I'm sure that a well built enterprise grade SAN would beat these sticks... we're on a gaming site.

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/usb-3.0-thumb-drive-review,review-32737-2.html http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/travelstar-7k1000-hdd-review,review-32746-3.html

Comment: @Jeeva If you look closer your links prove my point. Your charts shows some of the fastest using multiple chips in parallel. While there are faster thumbdrives the vast majority are NOT faster. If you know to pick one for speed you can, but the general public using whatever they've got are going to be at the same or lower speed.  Most sticks arn't even USB3.

Comment: @JamesRyan Great. So, assuming we're not advising anyone to buy 4x2GB USB2 sticks from Poundland / the dollar store, we can happily say "Yes, Flash can be faster and better," right? If your point is that awful storage is awful then you might be trying to answer the wrong question. OP also specifies that they will be using a USB3 connection.

Comment: @Jeeva We are not talking dollar store, we are talking 80% of thumbdrives on the market.  Unless you go and buy something specifically faster it won't be. So in answer to the OP's question will it *generally* be faster, the answer is no.

Comment: if the HDD and flash have the same maximum read/write speed listed... which would be better? That is my question.

Comment: @Mel: Ignoring price, max speed, capacity... It seems like this isn't much of a question, if I'm honest. I'd still root for a (emphasis) *good* flash drive (see my link, above) or a small SSD in a USB3 enclosure as in open-world or other non-linear games (such as Skyrim, Fallout 4, etc) you can't rely on everything being packed in the correct order for loading, and will get random models loaded at random times.

Comment: @Mel All other things being equal the SSD/flash will give better speed when things arn't packed well.  Power usage is another differentiator, flash uses about 1/3 of the power of an active HD but doesn't spin down, so if your specific usage involves long periods of inactivity it can use more battery.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start off by recognizing that the OP said they were not concerned about price, but then in a comment said they ruled out using an SSD because of price.  I think the OP has mistakenly assumed that a spinning disk or flash drive will be cheaper than an equivalently or better performing SSD.

They're wrong, especially given they only need about 64 or 128G, an SSD is the fastest and most economical option.  I'm interpreting the OP's need as "I need an external drive for gaming on a tight budget".

The tl;dr version is that spinning disk performance isn't in the same league as flash drives and SSDs.  A fast flash drive in the size you need will cost you $140.  Instead, for $60 you can buy a cheap SSD that will perform as well as that flash drive, for example the [Kingston SSDNow](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6733/kingston-ssdnow-v300-review) or the [OCZ Trion 100](http://hothardware.com/reviews/ocz-trion-100-series-480gb-and-960gb-ssd-reviews).  For $75 you can buy an excellent SSD such as the [Samsung 850 EVO](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8747/samsung-ssd-850-evo-review).

Here's the details.

---

There's a lot of very cheap, but very slow external drives out there. It's hard to know what's actually inside the enclosure, external drives rarely provide performance information. Let's ignore them and instead focus on putting a bare hard drive into an enclosure.

A decently fast spinning drive will cost you at least $50, for example a Seagate Barracuda, plus another $20 for an enclosure. If price is no object, there is the [WD VelociRaptor 600GB](http://hothardware.com/reviews/wd-velociraptor-600gb-fastest-hd-ever), one of the fastest mainstream spinning disk drives, but it's going to cost you $250 and it's going to suck power like nobody's business.  You can get a 300GB refurb for about $60.  At a max transfer rate of 145Mb/s it's only 1.5 to 2 times faster than the much cheaper Seagate Barracuda.  You're just not going to get huge performance gaps with a mature technology like spinning disk drives.

What about a hybrid drive, a spinning disk with a small SSD for cache? In 2012, when SSDs were expensive, they made sense as an economic compromise. In 2015, when SSDs are affordable, they're dead tech. They're only useful when you need a lot of fast disk space on a budget.  You can pick one up for about $80.  While it will outperform the Velociraptor for small, repetitive, easily cached transfers (usually having to do with the operating system) which will be using the SSD, large or infrequently used files (such as loading a new level) will not do well.

Flash drive performance varies wildly.  And you're going to want at least 64 GB to be safe (as a comparison, [Battlefield 4 wants 30 GB](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-4/pc)) which jacks up the price.  A fast flash drive of that size is going to be anywhere from $50 to $200 depending on how fast and how big.  A [Corsair Flash Voyager GTX 128G](http://www.corsair.com/en/flash-voyager-gtx-usb-3-0-128gb-flash-drive-b) is a good choice.  At $140, it can read three times faster than the Velociraptor.

Here's the "money is no option" lineup from slowest to fastest.

- Any hybrid drive
- WD VelociRaptor at $60 to $250 for about 140MB/s
- Corsair Flash Voyager GTX at $140 for about 450MB/s

Ok, what about an SSD?  The OP ruled them out because of price, but there's a number of well performing SSDs for $60.  The [Kingston SSDNow](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6733/kingston-ssdnow-v300-review) or the [OCZ Trion 100](http://hothardware.com/reviews/ocz-trion-100-series-480gb-and-960gb-ssd-reviews) will both perform *better* than the Flash Voyager GTX, especially at random reads and writes, at half the price.  Bump up to $75-$100 and you can get the amazingly well balanced [Samsung 850 EVO](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8747/samsung-ssd-850-evo-review).

---

This is all moot because with a brand new, graphics intensive FPS game like Fallout 4 your bottleneck will likely be your video card.  The OP said they have a [MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Technical_specifications_3) which means, fortunately, a dedicated GeForce GT 650M.  This *should* be better than the minimum requirements.  I'm making that assumption based on Battlefield 4 and Arma 3 having a minimum of the inferior GeForce 8800GT.  But it's not great.

Before you go spending money on hardware for a game that doesn't exist yet and we don't even know the system requirements, try running a game like Battlefield 4 or Arma 3 and see how that goes.

Comment: I wouldn't say the "slowest" SSD -- the top end Flash drives are practically small SSD devices (using the same type of memory as SSD even, MLC nand, etc) . With read/write speeds into the 300/400 megabyte per second range recently, they can be on par with current model mid- to low range SSDs. They aren't just for sneakernets anymore. :)

Comment: @lilbyrdie It's a moot point for the OP who is concerned about price. That flash drive will cost you at least $150. The SSD will be $50.

Comment: Perhaps. SSD + a good enclosure + a good cable -- I've had more enclosures fail than anything over the years -- can add up, in the end. Also, technically, he said to ignore price in the first paragraph. ;)

Comment: @lilbyrdie Yeah, I've had particular problems with the WD Elements drives. Move the laptop a bit and they disconnect. I don't have a recommendation for a good enclosure, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **BOTH.**

***Introducing the Hybrid Drive!*** *

You don't really see much in the press about HHDDs these days, and the only company that does them is Seagate, this is because in the majority of cases, users find SSDs to be cheap enough. However there continues to be a small niche in users who want to have fast random access in their humungous storage solutions, the Seagate HHDDs are pretty good.

However I would NOT connect a hybrid drive to a PC using USB3 if at all possible. You would get much better performance by attaching it via a eSATA connector. If your Mac lacks an eSATA connector, I would advise you to fork out for a [Thunderbolt-eSATA connector](http://www.apple.com/hk/shop/product/HGC82ZM/A/kanex-thunderbolt-to-esata-usb-30-adapter).

*No I don't mean attach a Prius to your laptop.

Comment: I am fairly sure it's SSHD, not HHDD.