# Running Genshin Impact on an SD card?

Tags: pc, genshin-impact

Does anyone know how to get Genshin Impact to run off an external SD card? This is on a PC with very low internal memory storage, so ideally I'd like for the game to be run off the external storage. However, I've read that there can be issues where the game tries checking internal memory for data and if it can't find it it tries to download files, regardless if everything is up to date in the external memory.

For clarification, the external memory I plan to run it on is a MicroSD card

Comment: I don't know about an SD card, but my installation runs just fine from a secondary drive in my laptop, so you can run it from an external drive, if that helps any.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231306/for-pc-gaming-on-external-storage-should-i-use-flash-or-hdd-hard-disk-drive?rq=1

Comment: The issue would probably be with the `%appdata%` folder, as a game might want to put files there. I don't know of any solutions though